# How to detect if camera cannot see it's target?

Tags: opengl, camera

I would like to know how can I detect if an obstacle(gray cube on the screenshot below) is hindering camera's vision on it's target(pink cube on the screenshot below) so that I can move the camera temporarily closer to the target.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You might look into occlusion queries to solve this problem. You can test if any GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, when drawing the pink cube. If no samples were rendered, you know the pink cube isn't being drawn. You might run into issues if the object is out of the viewing frustum and no samples will pass, so you will be getting a false positive, but you could do a frustum cull check and only if the frustum cull fails, then the object is in frame, and then if no samples pass the occlusion test, you can move your camera forward.

Comment: Isn't that forcing me to be at mercy of the gray cube, that I have to wait until it fully occludes pink cube?

Since posting this question I took interest in Ray-Box intersection testing and was thinking of introducing bounding volumes, but I am not convinced whether this is actually good technique for testing against static barriers like walls or fences.

Also, I didn't mention that It would be used to move 3rd person camera closer to the target, such that it doesn't go out of player's vision.

Comment: There are different occlusion queries, GL_SAMPLES_PASSED, can tell you how many samples passed... You could check if percentage occluded is over a certain threshold to move the camera.

Comment: Ray-box intersection might be a good choice too, would the algorithm test for visible corners?

Comment: Currently I am shooting a ray from the center of my target cube to the camera's position and test for nearby cubes - visible corners just aren't enough or I haven't come up with the right deduction thechniques.

Comment: Yes, ray box intersection sounds reasonable. Shoot a ray from the screen center into the screen if it hits the pink box center (ray-point distance is below a threshold) and it doesnt pass through other boxes. You might have to implement an acceleration structure for larger scenes.

Comment: Thank you for the term "acceleration structure" - the research has become much more convenient.